# How to pass variables in a loop in bash

Tags: bash

I found a script on the Internet(https://calomel.org/youtube_wget.html) that wgets youtube videos.

So the script works perfectly for a single clip by simple typing `./yt.pl youtubeLink` .
But I want to scale this up and use it from links in a text document (download.txt)
. So I created a loop in bash. The loop looks like this.

`

```
    #!/bin/bash
wordCount=$(cat download.txt | wc -l)

for (( number=$wordCount; $number-lt$wordCount;number--))
do
        link=$(sed -n $number"p" download.txt)
        "./yt.pl "$link
        sleep 3
done
```

The only problem with this it doesn't work. It gives me the following error message.

```
/auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYzUd95h8X4: No such file or directory
```

if I just run this part of the error message `./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYzUd95h8X4` it works fine.

Here is the complete output of the ssh window

```
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl : No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEAL23g2V6g: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYzUd95h8X4: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IaADyDhg-CY: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmY4RCCCll4: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0p5RKzuJLU: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sY6-PY9wWQ8: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRwcozVntTE: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ft5hp90FV74&feature=relmfu: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DB1E4M7bmeM: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6w4yeT6OTg&feature=relmfu: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-m88UZXn_8&feature=related: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iix8NxDN6mQ&feature=relmfu: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3DvUKEZP_0&feature=relmfu: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKVdSNfbilo: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3kjn1zM7OI&feature=relmfu: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhJheZepqqY&feature=relmfu: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=59Oj_xpxh_g&feature=relmfu: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLP8XMMEG0A: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCY5ZRXQ3u0&feature=relmfu: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a8CHv8n6qpI&feature=relmfu: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afJXLpC95lQ&feature=relmfu: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6q4dPeUjmu8&feature=relmfu: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0BY5V56ZW3w&feature=relmfu: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CO__3nHsg8: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzgZlV3LzFA&feature=fvst: No such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 7: ./yt.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgS1UQvYtcU&feature=fvst: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
#!/bin/bash

while read link; do
    ./yt.pl "$link" && sleep 3
done < download.txt
```

Comment: You should explain a little...The problem was the spacing and the quotes in `"yt.pl "$link` which was treated as a single (unfindable) file.  The fix is to separate `yt.pl` from `"$link"`.  It is also better to read one line at time with the `read` command than to repeatedly slice up a file with `sed`.